# Editing MySql database records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database located on my webserver that I frequently need to add records. What is an easy way to add/edit/delete records without having to login to my control panel, then login in to phpMyAdmin?

Also, If I could find a way for multiple users to add records, It would save me a lot of time from having to import lots of csv files.

An Android App for my Galazy Tab would be epic.

Comment: A CMS would do it, but you'd need to write or customize an existing one to work with your DB setup. You do NOT want to expose a database to the world at large - it's just begging for your DB to get subverted, and this what any ios/android-based mysql apps would require. That or a server-side proxy script.

Comment: You can use ConnectBot from your phone to SSH to the server, launch mysql client from the shell, and run raw SQL while sitting on the can. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an official MySQL GUI Query Browser/Administrator/Database Designer application that can be downloaded from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html). To use this you need to make sure that your server is configured to allow your MySQL user account to log in from a remote IP address.

Comment: I wouldn't go this route, check out my answer, it allows for better security while tunneling over SSH (and just as simple, I've given up phpmyadmin in favor of HeidiSQL).

Answer (score 2):

[Adminer](http://adminer.org/) is probably what you're looking for; it's a single PHP file you upload to your server. You just log in to the database (it'll save details for you), and off you got. Think PHPMyAdmin, but not as bloated.

It'll obviously work on your Galaxy Tab (jealous rant ensues; I want one!), as it's web based. It's also themable, if you're into that kind of thing.

Comment: Someone pointed out Adminer to me the other day, and it does look good from a simplicity standpoint.  I'm not sure the browse mode is any "lighter" from a web app standpoint, but it's certainly less files to install.

Comment: Well, I use it every day and it's definitely faster than PHPMyAdmin. Looks like you've found a solution to your problem, however, which is pretty much all that matters :-)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from writing your own webapp to do that (easily done in php for example) you could install phpMyAdmin in webspace.  phpMyadmin is simply a php based web application that is typically installed in control panel, but there is nothing preventing you from setting up and configuring your own copy.

With that said, and considering your desire to use your phone -- a really simplified form might be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create csv file with columns like in your db and use
LOAD DATA INFILE ...
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html.

But anyway you should have script maybe php which will get run this command for a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some simple web services in PHP. Just a script that receives an HTTP GET, and forms a SQL query out of that.

You can then create a android application consisting of one form (activity). The submit button on that form can send an HTTP GET request to your PHP web service and create a database record based on your form.

This is a good, beginner project. Just a couple hundred lines of code. When you start building it, post more specific questions, and someone will help you...

**Sample PHP web service:**

```
<?php
include "Utility/connect.php"; 
connect();   

$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['form_field_1']);
$body =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['form_field_body']);
$date = time();


//Create Entry in database
$createNode = "INSERT INTO my_form(date, body, subject) VALUES('$date', '$Body',$subject,)";
mysql_query($createNode) or die(mysql_error());




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would use is **`HeidiSQL`** as it allows MYSQL connections over SSH (you just tunnel your MYSQL traffic over).  No need to open mysql to the world, and you have a very powerful easy to use client at your fingertips.  Stop using phpmyadmin on your server, use HeidiSQL.

Here is the link **http://www.heidisql.com/**

later get plink.exe (for tunnel) and off you go, its a simple process to setup.